# Error while Netsuite Search customFields inside an Invoice

Tags: netsuite, invoice

I have a requirement to search the customFields and some  columns inside an invoice ,

searchRecord  works without customFieldList array , Can someone please help how to achieve this ?

Netsuite wsdl version : NetSuitePort_2020_2
Request I am using :

<ns0:searchRecord xmlns:ns03="urn:sales_2020_2.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns03:TransactionSearchAdvanced">
<ns03:criteria xmlns:ns03="urn:sales_2020_2.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com">
ns03:basic
<ns01:type xmlns:ns01="urn:common_2020_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" operator="anyOf">
<ns02:searchValue xmlns:ns02="urn:core_2020_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">_invoice</ns02:searchValue>
</ns01:type>
<ns01:customFieldList xmlns:ns01="urn:common_2020_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">

</ns01:customFieldList>
<ns01:dateCreated xmlns:ns01="urn:common_2020_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" operator="after">
<ns02:searchValue xmlns:ns02="urn:core_2020_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">2023-10-10T00:00:00.000-08:00</ns02:searchValue>
</ns01:dateCreated>
<ns01:mainLine xmlns:ns01="urn:common_2020_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
<ns02:searchValue xmlns:ns02="urn:core_2020_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">true</ns02:searchValue>
</ns01:mainLine>
</ns03:basic>
</ns03:criteria>

```
<ns03:columns xmlns:ns03="urn:sales_2020_2.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com">
    
           
    <ns03:basic>
      <internalId/>
      <nextApprover/>
      <entity/>
      <tranId/>
      <tranDate/>
      <terms/>
      <taxTotal/>
      <total/>
      <dueDate/>
      <status/>
    </ns03:basic>
</ns03:columns>
```

</ns0:searchRecord>
</ns0:search>

Error:            org.xml.sax.SAXException: Invalid type: SelectCustomFieldRef

I tried following the below netsuite documentations xml

https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_N3458179.html#bridgehead_N3460361